# How to Modify Event Rules @ JD Edwars System

Tags: jakarta-ee, oracle11g, jdedwards

I'm using a JD Edwards version 9.1 OneWorld Enterprises. how can i modify its event rule at a certain module let say at the process option module there was a certain field has 4 conditions. and i like to add 1 condition to it. probably it's like an IF condition statement there and i want to add another else if for the new condition "5"

My Question is how could i get to the Design place the new condition title and go to the program logic to add the function and formula?

does JD edward works like that? how do i modify the event rule? i have a JD Edward Solution Explorer which i tried to walk through at its Fast path "OMW" 
and try to look for options to modify the event and module but found nothing

is there a way i could add the event rule how?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a report or UBE then you use RDA. If it's an application or APPL then you use FDA.

- You must add the object to an OMW project;
- Check the object out into that OMW project;
- Design it;
- Check it in;
- Promote it.